# Azure in-role co-located caching: There is a temporary failure

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, appfabric, azure-caching, appfabric-cache

I have been battling to get **in-role, co-located caching** (not dedicated) working in Azure.

In my MVC WebApi 2 project's `web.config`:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="dataCacheClients" type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientsSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
</configSections>
...
<dataCacheClients>
  <dataCacheClient name="default" isCompressionEnabled="true">
    <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="MyWebApiProject" />
    <clientNotification pollInterval="300" />
    <transportProperties maxBufferSize="1073741824" maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824"/>
  </dataCacheClient>
</dataCacheClients>
```

Cache property setting on the role:

[image: Role Properties]

I got the following exception thrown in Azure:

> **Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException:**
>   ErrorCode:SubStatus:There is a temporary failure.
>   Please retry later. (One or more specified cache servers are
>   unavailable, which could be caused by busy network or servers. For
>   on-premises cache clusters, also verify the following conditions.
>   Ensure that security permission has been granted for this client
>   account, and check that the AppFabric Caching Service is allowed
>   through the firewall on all cache hosts. Also the MaxBufferSize on the
>   server must be greater than or equal to the serialized object size
>   sent from the client.). Additional Information : The client was trying
>   to communicate with the server: net.tcp://MyWebApiProject:24233.

When I turn `autoDiscover` off, like this:

```
<autoDiscover isEnabled="false" identifier="MyWebApiProject" />
```

Then I get a different exception:

> **Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException:**
>   ErrorCode:SubStatus:Server collection cannot be
>   empty.

I don't have any problems when running locally using the Compute Emulator.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885308/implement-azure-colocated-caching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I upgraded my Azure SDK from 2.2 to 2.3, this problem stopped occurring.

Comment: Just to add to this. The Azure SDK Tools and Azure DLL's from your NuGet packages must be the same version. These problems normally occur when you update one but not the other. Strange things always start to happen. If you upgrade the Tools you will need to go to your Azure project, right click and press properties, then press Upgrade.

Comment: @Adam: Yes, I have found similar behaviour. Thanks for the comment.